# audio using data uri displays error in mobile Chrome

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, html5-audio, mobile-chrome

Mobile Chrome (v45.2454.68) in iOS displays error when rendering the audio element using data uri.

It works in desktop Chrome, Safari and Firefox and also works in mobile Safari. Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Don't know why cannot add the example code link in the post. Here is the example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbGKWW

Comment: Tracking in chromium forum: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509556&q=audio%20uri&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified