# How to play audio from data URI in WebView?

Tags: android-webview, html5-audio, data-uri

✔ audio can be played from the internet

✔ images can be displayed from data URIs

✘ **audio can not be played from data URIs**

(Android 4.4.2)

Comment: I have tested with only 1 audio file. Should I try different files / encodings / dataURI-generators / settings?

Comment: ✘ shorter audio: still doesn't work

Comment: ✘ playing as mp4 video: doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert audio data uri string to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541898/convert-audio-data-uri-string-to-file)